# How to get field from GeoJSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, geojson

I get the following GeoJSON from my server:

> [{"st_asgeojson":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-180081.82,5279725.36]}"}]

How can I get the coordinates field? I have the GeoJSON stored in a *geovar* variable

I tried with `geovar["st_asgeojson"].coordinates`,`geovar[0]["st_asgeojson"].coordinates`, `geovar[0]["st_asgeojson"]["coordinates"]` but they seem to be undefined.

Any idea? I know it's pretty simple but I'm stuck with it. Thanks.

Comment: first of all you have to parse the JSON string

Comment: `var` is reserved word in javascript, use another name for your variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved this way:

> [{"st_asgeojson":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-180081.82,5279725.36]}"}]

is a JSON with a GeoJSON inside. Before parsing the GeoJSON I had to get the GeoJSON string from an already parsed JSON. The only neccesary instructions were:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(geovar[0]["st_asgeojson"]);
var coordinates = obj.coordinates;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `"st_asgeojson"` now is a string. You need to parse it to JSON before access it. Using `map` to loop through and parse the value of `"st_asgeojson"` with `JSON.parse`

```js
const geovar = [{"st_asgeojson":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-180081.82,5279725.36]}"}]

const rs = geovar.map(e => {
 e["st_asgeojson"] = JSON.parse(e["st_asgeojson"])
 return e
})

console.log(rs[0]["st_asgeojson"]["coordinates"])
console.log(rs)
```

Answer (score -1):

Which is you are getting from your server that is JSON String data.If you want to parse then first Make JSON using JSON.stringify() function. Hope that will solve your issue. After that you can easily parse your data as you want.